# Unable to install ros-noetic-effort-controllers "E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap"

Tags: ros, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! When trying to install the package effort_controllers in controller-manager (I am on ros noetic) via "sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-effort-controllers" I get the error:

```
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

The same happens when trying to install other packages from controller-manager, such as force-torque-sensor-controller, although joint-state-controller does get installed. After searching around, I found the following solutions:

(1) Tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`  and `apt-get update`

(2) Working around the problem by installing `apt-fast,` which acts as a wrapper for apt-get and seems to make the download process more resilient. https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast. However, this does also not work since when I try sudo apt-fast install ros-noetic-effort-controllers I get the error message:

```
[ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubunt... Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=3 URI=http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubunt... -> [HttpSkipResponseCommand.cc:218] errorCode=3 Resource not found
```

Any other suggestions? Or idea how to fix the apt-fast error? Or cause of the problem? (I feel like it has something to do with a dodgy server)

EDIT: the output of `sudo apt-get check`, as mentioned by Mike in the comments, is the following:

> Package lists are being read... Done

> Tree of requirements is being built

> Status information is being read...
> Done

---

SOLUTION
The final problem turned out o be that I had done two different ROS setups: one standard, following the ros noetic install page, and one via my company using another installation method. Thus it created two different sources.list.d, while I should actually have one. I removed the standard one and also removed its PPA.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385758/unable-to-install-ros-noetic-effort-controllers-%22e:-internal-error,-ordering-was-unable-to-handle-the-media-swap%22/) by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-06**:
I think this is a general Ubuntu issue, not really a ROS issue. I've never seen this error, but I think that `dist-upgrade` has screwed up the versions of libraries installed on your system. FYI, we **never** run `dist-upgrade` on our ROS machines.

What version of Ubuntu is this?

Please edit your question to include the full output of `sudo apt-get check`.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-07**:
Hi Mike! I have Ubuntu focal release 20.04. I edited the question with the output of `sudo apt-get check`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-07**:
I would suggest to take a step back: remove `apt-fast` (adding more software is almost never a solution to anything), undo whatever you did to your `sources.list` (or the files in `sources.list.d`) and then try again.

Also: what platform is this? A plain `amd64` machine, an RPi, something else? How did you install ROS? Which tutorials or instructions did you follow? What is the output of `uname -a`, did you add things to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or created a separate file (in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`)? etc, etc?

It's hard to help anyone without sufficient information.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-07**:
I am sorry for not providing enough information, I do not have that much knowledge on my PC/Ubuntu so I find it hard to decide what I should provide or what is going on. The output of `uname -a` is the following:

Linux jessie-HP-ZBook-Studio-G3 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I dod not add anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and did not create a separate file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-07**:\

> I dod not add anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and did not create a separate file.

so which ROS installation tutorial did you follow?

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-07**:
http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-07**:
And did you perform step 1.2 "Setup your sources.list"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The final problem turned out o be that I had done two different ROS setups: one standard, following the ros noetic install page, and one via my company using another installation method. Thus it created two different sources.list.d, while I should actually have one. I removed the standard one and also removed its PPA.

---

Originally posted by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) with karma: 18 on 2021-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0